# How do I fix AWS key file authentication error?

Tags: putty, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using an AWS ec2 instance. Previously I was connecting via Filezilla, Putty and MySQL using the provided key file with no problem. Now for some reason I am unable to access the sever.

Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

I have checked the public key is correct. I have checked the location of the ppk and pem files.

What else could be the cause of this error?

[image: FileZilla config]

[image: AWS EC2 instance]

Comment: This error means that the server is offering `publickey` as an authentication method, but your client isn't able to deal with it... are you sure the private key is valid, as is associated with the session's configuration?

Comment: Yes it was working previously, then something changed and now it is not working.

Comment: Is that "_something_" the session configuration? do you use `pagent.exe`? Is it running? Can you share a screenshot of the session config?...

Comment: Not sure exactly what I can share but here is a screenshot of the AWS setup - Link in description above

Comment: I was actually referring to the configuration of the client (i.e: FileZilla / Putty) - feel free to remove the AWS screenshot.

Comment: Added Filezilla configuration

Comment: As said above, it doesn't look like you're sending the key to the server properly. Have you configured it in your putty connection, or are you using [pagent](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter9.html) to store your keys.